# Package Manager Console crashes when using Add-Migration

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I am using Package Manager Console to add migrations to my database and for some reason it just freezes and does nothing.  The only way to stop it and continue using it is to close down Visual Studio using the Task Manager.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: 3 views only and no answers.  Moral of the story: don't use the most up to date things that are released. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a known issue, but I had the same problem, and found a solution for it.

I had to run:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MyContext -ProjectName MyProject.Framework -StartUpProjectName MyProject.Web
```

Where I specified:

- `-ContextTypeName` as the name of my context
- `-ProjectName` as the project that held my Context file
- `-StartUpProjectName` as the project that held the web application.

You can reference this resource for more information: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

Comment: Enable-Migrations is obsolete now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Sean Keating's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442679/771496), if it solved your "Enable-Migrations" problem, you must know that it might not be enough.

**Add-Migration**

To create a new migration script, you do it like you would do it normally:

```
Add-Migration MyModifications
```

**Update-Database**

To update the database though, you will have to specify your context's project:

```
Update-Database -ProjectName MyProject.Framework
```

Where I specified:

- `-ProjectName` as the project that held my Context file

Comment: @downvoter: Why ? Knowing you must also specify the project when you update the database is pretty important.

Comment: I wish people would add a comment when they down vote. It might be helpful. I up-voted this because adding the -ProjectName actually allowed my update-database to run successfully. Previously I was just using -StartupProjectName. This worked fine for creating a migration, but the update-database would crash. Note: I have multiple startup projects.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I suspect the reason for the downvote is that the other answer already includes details about the ProjectName option. This answer doesn't add anything.

Comment: Putting the project name during the `Enable-Migration` is different from what I proposed. Maybe that person did not see that. Who knows...